# Delete parent directory if file is present with appropriate timestamp

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell I'd like to search a directory tree which will have a subset of folders.  If a file called NOW is present within those folders and is 3 days old I'd like to delete the parent directory.

I think I have the search syntax right, then piping to a foreach loop but I can't figure out how to remove the parent directory.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\tools\test1 -Filter NOW -Recurse | 
    foreach ($_)   ???
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` returns `System.IO.FileInfo` objects for files. One of the properties is `Directory`. So what you would be wanting to remove the directory. The Directory is still and object and we need the full path from it.

```
Remove-Item $_.Directory.FullName -Force -Recurse
```

The above would remove the folder, where NOW resides, and its contents. But you have another condition for age. Couple of ways to do this but one would be to use `New-TimeSpan` to compare the creation time to Now. Using the `Days` property of the TimeSPam

```
(New-TimeSpan -start $_.CreationTime -end ([datetime]::Now)).Days -gt 3
```

Putting that together with what you already have. `-File` will ensure we dont get folder matches.

```
$refdate = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-3)
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\tools\test1" -Filter "NOW" -Recurse -File | 
        Where-Object{$_.CreationTime -gt $refdate} | 
        ForEach-Object{ Remove-Item $_.Directory.FullName -Force -Recurse -WhatIf }
```

The `-WhatIf` will help you identify the folders this process would attempt to remove. If you dont have at least PowerShell version 3 you could do this.

```
$refdate = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-3)
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\tools\test1" -Filter "NOW" -Recurse | 
        Where-Object{(!$_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.CreationTime -gt $refdate)} | 
        ForEach-Object{ Remove-Item $_.Directory.FullName -Force -Recurse -WhatIf }
```

Comment: For directories it returns a DirectoryInfo object. Files return FileInfo objects which do have different properties.

Comment: Im in the middle now of addressing that error. Thanks for the heads up @TheMadTechnician

Comment: I'd suggest calculating a reference date outside the pipeline (`$refdate = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-3)`) and then filter the results with `$_.CreationTime -gt $refdate`, so you don't waste resources calculating timespans over and over again. As for filtering out directories, simply add `-not $_.PSIsContainer` to the filter.

Comment: I suppose it is possible that a folder could be name "NOW" and picked up in this. @AnsgarWiechers thanks for the suggestions. It is what makes me better at this